# Android : fragment.isInLayout() not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to check whether my fragment is in the current `FrameLayout` or not? I have tried using `isInLayout()` as below:

```java
TertanggungPolis tertanggungPolis = (TertanggungPolis) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
if (tertanggungPolis.isInLayout()) {
    // doing something here
}
```

But it seems this code does not work for me. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to see if the fragment is visible? If so, there is the `isVisible()` method available.

```java
TertanggungPolis tertanggungPolis = (TertanggungPolis) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
if (tertanggungPolis.isVisible()) {
    // doing something here
}
```

If you really want to know if the fragment is a part of your FrameLayout, please post the xml. According to the docs, `isInLayout()` will definitely be true if you have the fragment node in your layout xml file, where the  node sits in the FrameLayout's hierarchy.

> isInLayout() Return true if the layout is included as part of an
> activity view hierarchy via the  tag. This will always be
> true when fragments are created through the  tag, except in
> the case where an old fragment is restored from a previous state and
> it does not appear in the layout of the current state.